# SQL Oracle: разделить строку на подстроки по переносу строки

Tags: sql, oracle

Просьба, подсказать, как корректно разбить строку на подстроки, разделителем является перенос строки,

пробовал разделить следующим способом, строка разделяется, но запрос уходит в бесконечное зацикливание и продолжает заново строить колонку дальше с теми же результатами,

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(dicts, '[^'||CHR(10)||']+', 1, LEVEL) AS dict
FROM table
WHERE id = 11111
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= REGEXP_COUNT(dicts, '[^'||CHR(10)||']+') + 1;
```

структура данной Ячейки которую пытаюсь разделить выглядит след. образом:

```
asd
Asd
Fgdt_
Fgdt.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

что-то типа такого, через опцию `'m'`

```
select 
    n, regexp_substr(dicts, '^.*$', 1, n, 'm') line
from 
    table,
    (select level n from dual connect by level <= (
        select regexp_count(dicts, '^.*$', 1, 'm') from table where id=1111
    ))
where id = 1111
order by n
```